# How to use a skeleton program in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dummy-variable

Here is a little look on how the dictionary program is built

```
dictionary = [
    ("thanks",["danke"]),
    ("always",["immer"]),
    ("us", ["uns"])
      ]
```

as u can see from the dictionary the strings comes in pair of

```
(string, [string])
```

Comment: remove the `return`s `return` in a *functional* language has different semantics compared to `return` in Java, C, C++, etc.

Comment: You should also work with recursion as a tool to enumerate over the dictionary

Comment: where did you define the `ys`/`y` variables?

Comment: You show `dictionary` as both a function of type `String -> String` and a list of type `[(String, [String])]`. Which is it?

Comment: the type is String -> String but the element of the list is in pairs and given as (String, [String])

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I think `String -> String` should be the type of `translate`, not of `dictionary`.

Comment: I've answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69224490/849891), see if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

> I have been given a dictionary in form of a skeleton program

No, you have been given a dictionary

```
dictionary :: [(String, [String])]
dictionary = [
    ("thanks",["danke"]),
    ("always",["immer"]),
    ("us", ["uns"])
      ]
```

and a type signature

```
translate :: String -> String
```

There isn't really any “skeleton” here, but you might call the following a *skeleton of `translate`*:

```
translate (x:xs) = _
```

What this would do is, try to select a suitable element from the dictionary for *the start of the input*. However, we're already on the wrong course because this *start of the input* `x` is just the first letter, whereas to match in the dictionary you need a whole word.

Fortunately, Haskell comes with a helper function to obtain the words in a given string, sensibly called [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words). So it would make sense to apply this to the input string, and then translate each word separately:

```
translate xs = translateWords (words xs)

translateWords :: [String] -> String
translateWords = _
```

or, if each word is supposed to be translated to a single other word,

```
translate = unwords . map translateWord . words

translateWord :: String -> String
translateWord = _
```

Here you don't need to worry about *deconstructing* a word further – there's nothing you could do with the individual letters. Instead, just make it

```
translateWord w = _
```

Now you could attempt matching the word `w` in the dictionary. Paraphrasing your attempt,

```
translateWord w
 | w`elem`dictionary  = y
 | otherwise          = " "
```

But *what is `y` now*? And the types don't match for this use of `elem`: that would require `dictionary` to be just a list of words, not of tuples.

So, what you need is a tool that doesn't just tell you whether an element *is in* a list, but rather whether it's in *the first tuple-part of an element* of the list, as well as what the other half of that tuple is. In other words, you're looking for a function of the signature

```
searchMatch :: a -> [(a,b)] -> b
```

Well, that's something [you can ask Hoogle about](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%5B%28a%2Cb%29%5D+-%3E+b). It gives one match in the `base` library:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

The `Maybe` is responsible for telling you whether a match was found at all. You can pattern-match on it:

```
translateWord w = case lookup w dictionary of
 Just wTranslations -> _
 Nothing            -> " "
```

Now the remaining `_` you should try to fill out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have been given a dictionary, to translate an input string, recursively compare every element in the second element of the head of the dictionary, to your input string.